# there is any way to draw shape on desktop using native api using java

Tags: java, native

i am able to draw circle on desktop but i can not draw transparent.
This is code for drawing circle on desktop.

```
 public static void drawCircle(int x, int y, int radius) {
    try {
        NativeCall.init();
        int brush = -1;
        IntCall ic = new IntCall("user32", "GetDesktopWindow");
        int screenHDC = ic.executeCall(new Object[]{});
        ic.destroy();
        ic = new IntCall("user32", "GetWindowDC");
        int hdc = ic.executeCall(new Object[]{screenHDC});
        ic.destroy();
        int pen = 0;
        ic = new IntCall("gdi32", "CreateSolidBrush");
        brush = ic.executeCall(new Object[]{0x000000FF});
        ic.destroy();
        VoidCall x1 = new VoidCall("Gdi32", "SelectObject");
        x1.executeCall(new Object[]{hdc, brush});
        x1.destroy();
        if (brush == -1) {
            ic = new IntCall("gdi32", "CreateSolidBrush");
            brush = ic.executeCall(new Object[]{0x00FFFFFF});
            ic.destroy();
            x1 = new VoidCall("Gdi32", "SelectObject");
            x1.executeCall(new Object[]{hdc, brush});
            x1.destroy();
        } else if (brush == 0) {
            ic = new IntCall("Gdi32", "CreatePen");
            pen = ic.executeCall(new Object[]{0, 3, 0x00FFFFFF});
            ic.destroy();
            x1 = new VoidCall("Gdi32", "SelectObject");
            x1.executeCall(new Object[]{hdc, pen});
            x1.destroy();
        }

        ic = new IntCall("gdi32", "Ellipse");
        ic.executeCall(new Object[]{hdc, x, y, (x + radius), (y + radius)});
        ic.destroy();


        ic = new IntCall("gdi32", "DeleteObject");
        ic.executeCall(new Object[]{pen});
        ic.destroy();
        ic = new IntCall("gdi32", "DeleteObject");
        ic.executeCall(new Object[]{brush});
        ic.destroy();
        ic = new IntCall("gdi32", "DeleteDC");
        ic.executeCall(new Object[]{hdc});
        ic = new IntCall("user32", "ReleaseDC");
        ic.executeCall(new Object[]{screenHDC, hdc});
        ic.destroy();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want draw 'transparent circle on desktop'.
There is any way to draw transparent shape on desktop window.

Comment: Are you sure that's the way you want to do it? Java2d might be a better api. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/

Comment: can we draw transparent shape on screen using java2d api?

Comment: A quick google search will provide you with an answer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html